# Reading Values from Textboxes in a .Net Deployment Project

Tags: .net, installation

I have a custom installer class that fires OnAfterInstall, how can I read values that were entered by the user in the pervious installation screens?  The values are entered in textboxes.

Also how can I force the installation to fail in my custom installer class and display an appropriate message to the user regarding the failure?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to pass the values from the previous text boxes from page to page via Hidden Fields, then read from those fields when OnAfterInstall is thrown.